# Close button also save values

Tags: c#, winforms, popup, parent-child

I have a dialog where the user can input two integers with OK button. The entered values are saved to variables. However, if I close it from the close button it also save the last entered values, which means not only the OK button save them. what am I doing wrong here?

The dialog:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public static class inputBoxDialog
    {
        public static void ShowDialog(string text1, string text2, string caption, int[] lastValue)
        {
            Form prompt = new Form();
            prompt.Width = 500;
            prompt.Height = 250;
            prompt.Text = caption;
            prompt.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            //input 1
            Label textLabel = new Label() { Left = 50, Top = 20, Text = text1 };
            NumericUpDown inputBox1 = new NumericUpDown() { Left = 50, Top = 50, Width = 400 };
            inputBox1.Value = lastValue[0];
            //input 2
            Label textLabe2 = new Label() { Left = 50, Top = 100, Text = text2 };
            NumericUpDown inputBox2 = new NumericUpDown() { Left = 50, Top = 130, Width = 400 };
            inputBox2.Value = lastValue[1];


            Button confirmation = new Button() { Text = "Ok", Left = 350, Width = 100, Top = 170 };
            confirmation.Click += (sender, e) => { prompt.Close();};

            prompt.Controls.Add(confirmation);
            prompt.Controls.Add(textLabel);
            prompt.Controls.Add(inputBox1);
            prompt.Controls.Add(textLabe2);
            prompt.Controls.Add(inputBox2);
            prompt.ShowDialog();
            lastValue[0] = (int)inputBox1.Value;
            lastValue[1] = (int)inputBox2.Value;

        }
    }
}
```

I call the dialog here:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Form
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        int[] loopParams = new int[2] { 0, 0 };
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            inputBoxDialog.ShowDialog("For Loop Begin: ", "For Loop End: ", "Popup", loopParams);
            //display the result
            label1.Text = "1:- " + loopParams[0]+"\r\n2:- " + loopParams[1];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ShowDialog()` returns a `DialogResult` value that you should test (and set correctly, e.g., setting the `confirmation` Button `DialogResult` property - so you also don't need a Click handler anymore).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by [Jimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7444103/jimi), you need to set the OK buttons `DialogResult` property to `DialogResult.OK`:

```cs
Button confirmation = new Button() { Text = "Ok", Left = 350, Width = 100, Top = 170, DialogResult = DialogResult.OK };
```

And to check the returned `DialogResult` value from the `prompt.ShowDialog()` method:

```cs
if (prompt.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    lastValue[0] = (int)inputBox1.Value;
    lastValue[1] = (int)inputBox2.Value;
}
```

Here is your code with the above additions:

```cs
public static void ShowDialog(string text1, string text2, string caption, int[] lastValue)
{
    Form prompt = new Form();
    prompt.Width = 500;
    prompt.Height = 250;
    prompt.Text = caption;
    prompt.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    //input 1
    Label textLabel = new Label() { Left = 50, Top = 20, Text = text1 };
    NumericUpDown inputBox1 = new NumericUpDown() { Left = 50, Top = 50, Width = 400 };
    inputBox1.Value = lastValue[0];
    //input 2
    Label textLabe2 = new Label() { Left = 50, Top = 100, Text = text2 };
    NumericUpDown inputBox2 = new NumericUpDown() { Left = 50, Top = 130, Width = 400 };
    inputBox2.Value = lastValue[1];


    Button confirmation = new Button() { Text = "Ok", Left = 350, Width = 100, Top = 170, DialogResult = DialogResult.OK };
    confirmation.Click += (sender, e) => { prompt.Close(); };

    prompt.Controls.Add(confirmation);
    prompt.Controls.Add(textLabel);
    prompt.Controls.Add(inputBox1);
    prompt.Controls.Add(textLabe2);
    prompt.Controls.Add(inputBox2);
    if (prompt.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // OK 
        lastValue[0] = (int)inputBox1.Value;
        lastValue[1] = (int)inputBox2.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        // Cancel
    }
}
```

Checking the `prompt.DialogResult` in the `prompt.FormClosed` event:

```
prompt.FormClosed += (sender, e) => 
{
    if (prompt.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // OK 
    }
    else
    {
        // Cancel
    }
};
```

Comment: Hello Eliahu, I have one more question here, in my parent form I have the line ```label1.Text = "1:- " + loopParams[0]+"\r\n2:- " + loopParams[1];```. I want to prevent this line from excuting if the child prompt close from X button. I couldn't manage. Do you know how can I do it

Comment: @MesopotamianLion: I'm not sure where is that line in your form but if it happens before the closing, your can handle it in a `prompt.FormClosed` event, check the `prompt.DialogResult` value and if it is different from `DialogResult.OK`, reset the value to whatever you need.

Comment: @MesopotamianLion: I added an example to the end of the answer.

Comment: The code you added in the child, right? but I want to prevent the line in the parent from excuting if the child closed from close button

Comment: @MesopotamianLion: Add an `else` to the `if (prompt.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)` (as I added just now to the example) and handle there when the `prompt` was closed with the X button (when closed by the X button, the `prompt.DialogResult` is `DialogResult.Cancel`).

Comment: Yes it worked but I wished to read out the Child DialogResult in the parent and then based on the result I excute my code.

Comment: Thanks Eliahu, I was able to solve my problem by creating variable and set it in the child based on the DialogResult then I used it in the parent.